# PHP: mail() function doesn't work on long html messages

Tags: php, html, email

Here is my code:

> ```
>     $message = '
>     <html>
>     <body>
>     <table>
>     <tr>
>     <td>
>     <img src=http://www.mdrnfx.com/mail_ust.jpg>
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>     <td>
>     <br>
>     <div align=justify>
>     <p>
>     <strong>Bugün  demonuzun 2. günü…</strong>
>     <br />Öncelikle  bizi tercih ettiğiniz için teşekkür ederiz.
>     <br />Forex  piyasasını tanıma ve öğrenme aşamasında mısınız?
>     <br />Platformun  kullanımı konusunda desteğe mi ihtiyaç duyuyorsunuz?
>     <br />Dilediğiniz  saat için uzaktan bağlantıya geçerek, size yardımcı olmaktan memnuniyet  duyacağımızı bilmenizi isterim.
>     <br />Bu  yönde bir talebiniz var ise lütfen aşağıdaki butonu tıklayın, dilediğiniz zaman  sizi arayalım.
>     <br />Evet  – hayır
>     <br />Evet  ise;
>     <br />Sizinle  ne zaman iletişime geçelim : …………………..
>     </p>
>     <p>
>     Aklınıza  takılan her konuda dilediğiniz; zaman bizimle temasa geçebilirsiniz…
>     </p>
>     <p>
>     Saygılarımla
>     <br />
>     <b>' . $_SESSION['adminName'] . '</b>
>     <br />Tel:<b> 0216 545 48 44</b>
>     <br />Msn:<b>' . $_SESSION['adminMsn'] . '</b>
>     </p>
>     Skype: <b>' . $_SESSION['adminSkype'] . '</b>
>     </div>
>     <br>
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>     <td>
>     <img src=http://www.mdrnfx.com/mail_alt.jpg>
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     </table>
>     </body>
>     </html>
>     ';  
>     $subject = "ModernFx - 2. Demo Gününüz";
>     $name = "ModernFx";
>     $gonderen = $_SESSION['adminMail'];
>     $mailler = $_POST['mailler'];
>     $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
>     $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
>     $email = explode("\n", $mailler);
>     unset($email[sizeof($email)-1]);;
>     //$headers .= "From: ".$name." <".$gonderen.">";
>     echo $message;
>     echo $headers;
>     $i = 0;
>     $count = 1;
>     while( $i <= (sizeof($email)-1) )
>     {
>           if( mail($email[$i], $subject, $message, $headers) )
>           {
>             echo " $count > <b>".$email[$i]."</b> <font color=green>Adresine Teslim Etti...</font><br><hr>";
>             $count++;
>           }
>           else 
>           echo " <b>".$email[$i]."</b> <font color=red>Hata gitmedi</font><br><hr>";
>           $i++;
>     }
> ```

It doesn't work with the line `//$headers .= "From: ".$name." <".$gonderen.">";` either..
Error reporting and display errors is on in php.ini and is set to -1.

Any help?

Comment: not sure if its related but `unset($email[sizeof($email)-1]);;` has two semicolons.

Comment: An extra semicolon shouldn't cause any kind of problem.  Is the error on messages of any size or just on this particular one?

Answer (score 1):

Better, use  MIME PEAR and save yourself a lot of trouble and time...

http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/redirected

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the charset and dreamweaver. I've checked the bare file, and the characters were messed up. So, the problem was dreamweaver, checked the encoding, it says west europe.. Na a, should be ISO-8859-9 or UTF-8.. So, I've chosen UTF-8 and retyped, there you go!

Answer (score 0):

This is my code I always use it to send emails , you can try it

```
<?

$sendTo   = $uemail;
$subject  = "Email Subject";
$headers  = "From: Name<noreply@name.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$message  = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            </head>
            <body>

            </body>
            </html>';

mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```